# 90's Anime: High-tech tank with many secret features

Tags: story-identification, anime

I exhausted my resources on finding an anime that I watched as a child.  I vaguely remember the whole plot but what I remember is the protagonist got a tank from his Father. I don't quite remember if his father leaves it behind or his father gave it to him.  The protagonist discovers that the tank/machine has a secret.  It is technologically advanced.  He discovers a secret compartment or button.

I believe that it was a series because I remember watching it everyday. I guess around age 8-12.  It was designed very differently like a high-tech tank with many secret buttons/features.

Comment: Was this a series or a movie? Was the protagonist a boy or a man? Did he go to school or did he have a job? Was he in the military? What did the 'tank' look like, in terms of shape and colour? Did it closely resemble a real world tank, or was the design very different?

Comment: I believe that's a series because i remember watching it everyday. I guess around age 8-12 it was designed very differently like a high-tech tank with many secret button/features.

Comment: You could check the following that somewhat fit your criteria: 1. Tank Knights Portriss 2. Mazinger Z 3. Gundam Wing. Hope it helps.